# Having problems with file permission on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, file-permissions, administrator, privileges

This problem started when I put my HDD on another computer that has my OS. Some of my programs won't open because I don't have sufficient privileges. The message said to contact the administrator of this machine.

Comment: If you were changing (upgrading) computers, the prior computer / OS was likely OEM and not transferable. That and driver differences could have caused this.

Comment: I just put the HDD in the other computer that has my OS on it and put it back on my machine when I was done.

Comment: You may have to take ownership of the files on which you have no permissions. The user account on the other computer was different than yours.

Comment: When upgrading your computer you should start with a fresh operating system for that computer. Simply moving your HDD across containing your old OS into the new machine is a very very dirty way to do it.. and will open up a massive can of worms. From file ownership to driver issues.. (even if win update corrects them).. just start fresh and then copy your important files over to the new system.